# How to get returned items in custom store credit email?

Tags: magento2, product, creditmemo

I have created a custom store credit email template, that will be used to sent as email for credit memo.

I am not much sure how do i add the returned items in it.

I have used `{{layout handle="sales_email_order_creditmemo_items" creditmemo_id=$creditmemo_id order_id=$order_id}}` but its not working in custom template
Any thoughts ?

Comment: any thoughts ??

Comment: any thoughts ??